# Bash:Single Quotes and Double Quotes and Exclamation Mark

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a simple script named `example`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $'${1}'
```

Please note that the usage of `$''` here is to convert `\n` into new line.
`${1}` is the first parameter passed to this shell script.

I want to pass a parameter to this script `example` and it prints the following:

```
#1. You're smart!
#2. It's a difficult question!
```

I tried the following:

```
example "#1. You're smart!\n#2. It's a difficult question!"
```

An error: `-bash: !\n#2.: event not found`

Then I tried to escape `!` by single quote, and tried:

```
example '#1. You're smart\!\n#2. It's a difficult question\!'
```

It outputs:

```
${1}
```

Any solution here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mat provides the perfect solution! Thanks to Chris Jester-Young and Jan Hudec too. U r all experts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat t.sh
#! /bin/bash
echo -e $@
```

Or `echo -e $1`, or `echo -e ${1}` if you just want to process the first argument.

To get bash to stop trying to expand `!`, use `set +H` (see [In bash, how do I escape an exclamation mark?](https://superuser.com/questions/133780/in-bash-how-do-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark))

```
$ set +H
$ ./t.sh "#1. You're smart!\n#2. It's a difficult question!"
#1. You're smart!
#2. It's a difficult question!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But mine wont work while yours can:Script is `echo -e ${1}` and use `example "#1. You're smart!\n#2. It's a difficult question!"` it prints `#1. You're smart\!
#2. It's a difficult question\!` Please note `\!` but I want `!`.

Comment: I have edited my comment. The newline works but I want '!' while it prints '\!'.

Comment: there's something else wrong then, using `${1}` (or plain `$1`) won't change anything to the output. try starting a new shell, maybe you've screwed your environment a bit.

Comment: Wahts your version of bash? I am on centos 5.5. My script is `echo -e ${1}` and input is `"#1. You're smart!\n#2. It's a difficult question!"`. It errors this time: `-bash: !\n#2.: event not found`

Comment: Mine version is GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: The important bit regarding `!` is the `set +H` command (or `set +o histexpand`). (I'm using Bash 4.1.9 but that shouldn't change anything.)

Comment: I see finally. It is `set +H`. I didnt use it b4. Whats this? Do I have to use it every time when I run a script?My script works now! Huge Thanks !!

Comment: there's a linked question on there, please read it. yes, this is per session. use `man bash` and search for `histexpand` to see how it works and other options.

Comment: You should double-quote the variables when you use them (e.g. `echo -e "$@"` or `echo -e "$1"`), or some other substitutions will happen inside the script.  This isn't a problem with `!` and `\n`, but with things like shell wildcards, multiple spaces, and a few other things.

Answer (score 2):

What's inside a `$''` expression has to be a literal. You can't expand other variables inside it.

But you can do this:

```
echo "${1//\\n/$'\n'}"
```

Jan Hudec has an even better answer:

```
echo -e "$1"
```

Comment: Echo knows to interpret escape sequences itself! It is done in a different way in different shells, but as long as only bash is requested, `echo -e "$1"` will do the trick.

Comment: I know single quote wont expand variables. But I need newlines. `$''` seems to be the only solution.

Comment: @Jan: Yep, true. I'll add your answer too. :-)

Comment: @DocWiki: I've edited my answer to use `$''`, but in a different way from how you were using it.