# Escape file name for use in sed substitution

Tags: linux, bash, variables, sed, escaping

How can I fix this:

```
abc="a/b/c"; echo porc | sed -r "s/^/$abc/"
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown option to `s'
```

The substitution of variable `$abc` is done correctly, but the problem is that `$abc` contains slashes, which confuse `sed`. Can I somehow escape these slashes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [GNU manual for `sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) states that *"The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command."*

Therefore, just **use another character instead of `/`**, for example `:`:

```
abc="a/b/c"; echo porc | sed -r "s:^:$abc:"
```

1. **Do not use a character that can be found in your input.** We can use `:` above, since we know that the input (`a/b/c/`) doesn't contain `:`.
2. **Be careful of character-escaping.**

   - If using `""`, Bash will interpret some characters specially, e.g. `` ` `` (used for inline execution), `!` (used for [accessing Bash history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6016664/974531)), `$` (used for accessing variables).
   - If using `''`, Bash will take all characters literally, even `$`.
   - The two approaches can be combined, depending on whether you need escaping or not, e.g.:

     ```
     abc="a/b/c"; echo porc | sed 's!^!'"$abc"'!'
     ```

Comment: WOw, what an excellent solution. I had no idea you can use something different than '/'. Even now that I know it, I can't find it in the manual.    
Thanks you all!

Comment: @haelix I have now added a reference to the manual, which describes this "trick", and much more.

Answer (score 7):

Note that `sed(1)` allows you to use different characters for your `s///` delimiters:

```
$ abc="a/b/c"
$ echo porc | sed -r "s|^|$abc|"
a/b/cporc
$
```

Of course, if you go this route, you need to make sure that the delimiters you choose aren't used elsewhere in your input.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `/` as pattern and replace separator, as others already told you. I'd go with `:` as it is rather rarely used in paths (it's a separator in PATH environment variable). Stick to one and use shell built-in string replace features to make it bullet-proof, e.g. `${abc//:/\\:}` (which means replace all `:` occurrences with `\:` in `${abc}`) in case of `:` being the separator.

```
$ abc="a/b/c"; echo porc | sed -r "s:^:${abc//:/\\:}:"
a/b/cporc
```

Comment: Well, actually it's not _that_ bulletproof, as `\n` and such in `$abc` will still get interpreted, but it's one step closer.

Answer (score 1):

backslash:

```
abc='a\/b\/c'
```

space filling....

Comment: It tends to be fiddly to get the backslashes into that string, not least because you have to work out when the shell is going to interpret them and when `sed` is going to interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

As for the escaping part of the question I had the same issue and resolved with a double sed that can possibly be optimized.

```
escaped_abc=$(echo $abc | sed "s/\//\\\AAA\//g" | sed "s/AAA//g")
```

The triple A is used because otherwise the forward slash following its escaping backslash is never placed in the output, no matter how many backslashes you put in front of it.